# Show that $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n$ are independent

Tags: probability, measure-theory

> Let $(X_1,X_2,\ldots , X_n)$ be a probability vector.
>
> If $E[g_1(X_1)\ldots g_n(X_n)]=E[(g_1(X_1)]\ldots E[g_n(X_n)]$ for all measurable functions $g_1,g_2,\ldots ,g_n:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that the expectations exist.
>
> Show that $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n$ are independent.

I am not sure how to start the problem.
Can someone please give some hints where to start it and how to complete it?

Answer (score 2):

Take $g_i= \mathbb{1}_{x \in A_i}$ for each $i$. Then you will get $P(X_1 \in A_1,..., X_n \in A_n) = \prod P(X_i \in A_i)$.Then taking the $A_i = (-\infty, x_i]$ will give you $F_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n) = \prod F_{X_i}(x_i)$.

Comment: What is $F$? I dont understand

Comment: $F_{X_i}(x_i) = \mathbb{P}(X_i \leq x_i)$ is the CDF of $X_i$. $F_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,..., x_n)$ is the joint CDF of $(X_1,...,X_n)$.